# just the opposite which

Tags: meaning-in-context

Can anyone help me about the following passage? 
We’re walking a tightrope in that country, giving the king every assurance but encouraging him to be decisive. **He has been just the opposite which** has aggravated an already bad situation.

the phrase in bold is especially problematic. The reference of the pronoun "which" is uknown for me. 
Thanks very much.

Answer (score 2):

I believe this example below will explain well.

from [WHICH | meaning in the Cambridge English Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/which):

> used to add extra information to a previous clause, in writing
>   usually after a comma:
>
> *He showed me round the town, which was very kind of him.*

So your sentence means:

He has been just the opposite, which has aggravated an already bad situation.

Usually there's a comma.